# Ember.js outlets and routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been trying to learn Ember.js for the last two weeks and I've really struggled.  I'm hoping for an 'a-ha' moment but each new feature I try to implement always results in hours of failed testing.  I just don't seem to be grasping the framework.  I feel like I'm working against it.  I'm hoping someone can explain a path forward through this simple example.

I am creating a web app that allows the user to pick products that they will sell to a client.  There is a list of products they can chose from and then a list of products they've selected.

I imagine a left-column with navigation controls and a main column showing either the selected products or new products they can add to the order.  Here is the basic template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="pc">
    <div id="nav">{{outlet nav}}</div>
    <div id="main">{{outlet main}}</div>
</script>
```

Here is the left navigation template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nav">
    <div class="button">{{#linkTo "pc.add"}}Add Products{{/linkTo}}</div>
</script>
```

Here is the selected products template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="selectedProducts">
    {{#each p in controller}}
        <div class="product">
            <h4>{{p.name}}</h4>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here is the available products template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="addProducts">
    <div id="addProducts" class="addProducts">
        {{#each p in controller}}
            <div class="product">
                <h4>{{p.name}}</h4>
            </div>
        {{/each}}   
        <button {{action "addSelectedProducts"}}>Add Selected Products</button>
        <button {{action "back"}}>Back</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

I can load the 'pc' template with some already selected products.  Great.  I can also navigate to the 'Add Products' template.  Great.  But when I click 'Add Selected Products', I can't figure out how to move the selected products into the controller/model behind the 'Selected Products' template and then get that template to re-render in place of the 'Add Products template'.  It's really two question.  How do I update the model of another controller from within a different controller?  And, how do I then transition from an event to another route?

Can someone show me how you would design the Route(s) and Controllers?  I know that's asking a lot.  I"m mostly interested in seeing how you respond to an event in the AppProductsController, update SelectedProductsController's model, and then transition to SelectedProductsRoute and have it re-render the template.

I want to believe this is an amazing framework but I just keep hitting walls.

Andrew

Comment: DO you have a link to what you have already, or can you create something similar to what you've tried on JSBin.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I update the model of another controller from within a different controller?

Connect controllers using the needs property. So something like:

```
//in AddProductsController
needs: ['selectedProducts']
addSelectedProducts: function() {
  // Now selectedProductsController can be accessed via the controllers property
  otherController = this.get('controllers.selectedProducts');
  // add the selected ones...
}
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

> how do I then transition from an event to another route?

```
//in AddProductsController
this.transitionToRoute('blogPosts');
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute

Comment: This is more or less correct.  I was confused that there are different ways to access controllers when you're in one Controller or when you're in a Route.  When you're in a Controller, you use 'needs:' and then 'this.get("controllers.someController")'.  But when you're in Route, you use this.controllerFor('someController').  I think I just never put it all together at the same time.  It's finally starting to click!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped. FWIW @darthdeus has a great post explaining controller needs - http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/